# How to randomise an output

Tags: java, random, arraylist, output, println

Say I had 3 outputs:

```
System.out.println("output 1");
System.out.println("output 2");
System.out.println("output 3");
```

How would I make it so only one of the outputs printed, and the one that was printed is random every time?

Comment: Check out these sites to see how to generate random numbers:  http://www.cs.geneseo.edu/~baldwin/reference/random.html http://java.about.com/od/javautil/a/randomnumbers.htm http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this with Math.random().

First, generate a random number between 0 and 3:

```
int randomNum = (int)Math.random() * 3;
```

Next, use if-else statements to choose which statement to print:

```
if(randomNum == 0)
   //print case 1
else if(randomNum == 1)
   //print case 2
else //print case 3
```

Comment: I haven't seen that method of generating a random number before, and I thought it was wrong. I did some research and now it makes perfect sense... Thank you for teaching me something new!

Answer (score 5):

```
// Collect all the possible outputs.
String[] outputs = new String[] { "output 1", "output 2", "output 3" };
// Use the core library class java.util.Random to get a source of pseudo-randomness.
Random random = new Random();
// Pick one and print it.
System.out.println(outputs[random.nextInt(outputs.length)]);
```

[`nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) returns a pseudo-random number uniformly distributed between 0 and its argument - 1.

Since `Random` is pseudo-random, if you need the output to be unguessable even by someone who observes many of your random choices, use `SecureRandom` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Put the strings to print in a `String` array and then generate random number up to the size of this array. Print the `String` at the index generated.

Comment: @String.userName Mike Samuel has already shown that in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `java.util.Random` class to generate a random `int` and then just use a simple `if` statement to print the corresponding output.

Answer (score 1):

The most conceptually simple way to do this is probably to create a random integer and use a switch statement and cases to select each output.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple implementation:

```
String[] str = { "Output1", "Output2", "Output3" };
Random r = new Random();
System.out.println(str[r.nextInt(3)]);
```